# Problems understanding Java InputStream read method

Tags: java, inputstream

let's say I got an Inputstream. Correct me if I am wrong, but all data in an InputStream are saved as bytes, for example the following text:
"Why not with ♥?"
Now I am wondering, how this text is converted to a byte-array, because I don't get how (for example) that ♥ is saved.
If I call

```
InputStream myInputStream = os.getInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1];
while ((in.read(b)) != -1) {
            System.out.write(b, 0, 1);
}
```

then my byteArray (with length of 1) will be filled with the next byte in every loop.

```
int.read(b)
```

returns an integer value, which is later be converted to a character.
So, if I take a look at the Java documentation, you will find something like this:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to 255.

My mind says: only 255 different characters possible? There must be a error in reasoning, because it doesn't matter which characters where used in my source.

So - can anyone help me with this brain teaser? Thx a lot.

Comment: *"255 different characters possible?"* If you split a 2-byte-character (just an example) into two single-byte-characters, then yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process of converting characters to bytes (and vice-versa) is called "character encoding". And it can be done in many different ways. The rules for those transformations are contained in what Java calls a [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). And Java supports many of them: ASCII, UTF_8, UTF_16, ISO_8859_1, etc. The standardones can be found in [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

Some charsets consider that the mapping between byte and character is one-to-one. ISO_8859_1 (AKA latin-1) is one of them. But there is a drawback of course: only 256 characters are encodable to bytes using such a charset (the occidental latin characters for ISO_8859_1).

Some others, like UTF_8, use one, two or more bytes per character, depending on the character. ASCII characters (a-b, A-B, digits, etc.) are encoded on a single byte, whereas others (accented letters, chinese, cyrilllic and other letters) use two or more bytes. The drawback is that it's harder to encode and decode, but the advantage is huge: every possible Unicode character is supported by such an encoding.

Just keep in mind that a byte and a character are two very different things, and that there is no one-to-one mapping between them. Use an InputStreamReader to read characters, and an OutputStreamWriter to write characters. Always specify a charset: not doing so will use the default encoding of **your** system (which might not be the same as anothe system).

Answer (score 0):

A character that requires 2 bytes contains a flag (in the first byte) that notifies whoever wants to know (including text editors) that it requires another byte.

In your case you read the first byte as a whole, including the flag, then it read the second. It's the text editor or console, that append them.